# Session Bounced with AWS ELB with multiple instance?

Tags: session, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, oscommerce, elastic-load-balancer

I am facing an issue with AWS ELB with multiple Server with LAMP for an ecommerce webstite.

When an user login with domain, which is pointed at AWS ELB, the session is bounced automatic ever (User is logout). I am trying with enable sticky session for both application and duration.

But my issue is not solved, when i am pointing domain direct ec2 instance without elb, everything working fine.

My ecommerce website is on oscommerce.

Please suggest me for this case.

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely an issue with session stickiness on your ELB.

An ELB has two options for stickiness, an application generated cookie that if you enter the name of the AWS ELB will generate it's own cookie from that cookie and build stickiness upon that, or you can have the ELB generate it's own cookie and maintain stickiness this way.

I suggest that you use **"Enable load balancer generated cookie stickiness"**.

To confirm it's working, if you inspect the website's cookies you should see a cookie named AWSELB and the cookie data shouldn't change between page loads.